# Is it possible to play a movie file in a UIView layer?

Tags: iphone, video, uiview

If yes, what movie format has best performance? And how would a simple setup look like? I have some views, and I want to play a short movie inside a view (not fullscreen). The movie is about 5 seconds long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's only 5 seconds long, you can fake it by playing the audio file in the background, and an animated UIImageView at the same time.  Lots of apps do this like the ~50 or so baby sign language ones.

Comment: Be careful, if you have a large view you want to animate, especially on the iPad, you can run into memory bandwidth issues which can kill performance and trigger memory warnings.  It's best to do this only with small animated images.

Comment: @Javy agreed.  It's quite a hack

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the system frameworks only support playing video full screen with the [`MPMoviePlayerController`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AudioandVideoTechnologies/AudioandVideoTechnologies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH19-SW12). Supported formats are basically flavors of H.264 and MPEG-4; more [in the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/iPhoneOSTechnologies/iPhoneOSTechnologies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898-CH3-SW10).

Theoretically, you might be able to roll your own decoding and playback code, but I doubt you'd get acceptable performance. (And most of the Open Source media player examples I can think of are GPL. Not that I imagine they'd fare much better.)